# Installing libssh2

Tags: php, ssh

Does anyone know how to install libssh2 into php on a windows environment?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, PHP bindings for libssh2 are still not very "portable": you'll really have less problems if you install some Linux in a virtual machine with your PHP+WebServer there. I recommend graphical Ubuntu version: you'll be rather easy with it: it has a big community and lots of issues solved on different forums. Also you'll gain experience with server OSes. ServerFault is at your service if you ever have some problems :)

Comment: +1 PHP does not belong on Windows.  That said, PHP doesn't really belong on any production systems.